# Сортировка по содержанию  на js

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Допустим, у нас есть таблица:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Заголовок</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Привет</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Пока</td><td>2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Каким образом, с помощью javascript, можно сделать выборку по этой таблице? Т.е. я ввел в  html форму в input значение 1 и все строки, чей id меньше 1, пропали.

Comment: Ну, как-бы, цикл и, как-бы, прятать элементы которые не соответствуют условию

Comment: все строки, чей id меньше 1, пропали.можно увидет эти строки и эти id?

Comment: "Можно увидет эти строки и эти id?"
Это не особо важно, они могут просто пропасть, могут быть перенесены в другую таблицу - в любом случае, в первой таблице они не должны показываться. AlexWindHope, я больше по php специализируюсь, с js плохо разбираюсь, можете пример предоставить или ссылки на материалы, которые помогут?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- warning - dirty realization :) -->
<table id="tableId">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Заголовок</th>
   <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Привет</td>
     <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Пока</td>
     <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function func( v ) {
  v = parseInt( v );
  if(!isNaN(v) && isFinite(v)) {
   var root = document.getElementById('tableId');
   var trs = root.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName('tr'), rowsTotal = trs.length;
   for( var i=0; i<trs.length; ++i ) {
    var tr = trs[i];
    var tdValue = parseInt( tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML );
    var displayStyle = tdValue < v ? 'none' : '';
    tr.style.display = displayStyle;
   }
  }
 }
</script>
<input type="text" onblur="func( this.value )">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function func(val){
    for(var i=1;i<val;i++){

        document.getElementById(i).style.display='none';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" value="" onblur="func(this.value)"  />
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
<div id="5">5</div>
```

Пример говно.Тебе нужно добавить в Input возможность добавлять в поле только натуральные числа(через регуляры).Много слышал что Id не можут начинатся с цифр.Поэтому лучше сделать айдишники в форме id="a1",id="a2",id="a3"...(аналогично через регулярки искать их и скрывать).

Comment: Ошибка в коде - здесь перебираются все id, которые меньше val, но если val установить как 2, и если будет 10 элементов на странице, только 2 элемента пройдут проверку

Comment: Извеняюсь я не совсем понимаю.Айдишники уникальны.C 10 элементов переберет их все ,но скроет только максимум val.